# Show different classification classes as different colors on a timeseries plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, bokeh

I want to visualize a line plot of time series with different classes in the background in **python**.

Suppose if I have time series of 5 minutes with 3 classes as shown in the **table 1**.

| Time start | Time End | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 00:00:30 | 1 |
| 00:00:31 | 00:01:30 | 2 |
| 00:01:31 | 00:04:00 | 3 |
| 00:04:01 | 00:05:00 | 2 |

I also have pressure values every 10 seconds shown in **table 2**.

| Time End | Pressure |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:10 | 0.2 |
| 00:00:20 | 0.3 |
| 00:00:30 | 0.53 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 00:04:50 | 0.7 |
| 00:05:00 | 0.92 |

I want to plot a line graph on top of the classes with different colors as shown in the figure below. The line plot follows the table 2 and the background color of the line plot follows table 1.
[image]

I am open to use any python library that could help me complete this visualization.

Comment: in bokeh, you could do this with BoxAnnotation : http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_3.html, http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.BoxAnnotation

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really for general advice like this... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JodyKlymak with all due respect, it is a pointed question. I still apologize if the question didn't meet the standard. I have read the article and will try to implement the ideas presented there in my next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
# convert timestamp to seconds
df2['Time End'] = pd.to_timedelta(df2['Time End']).dt.total_seconds()
df1['Time start'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Time start']).dt.total_seconds()
df1['Time End'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Time End']).dt.total_seconds()

# plot line
ax = df2.plot(x='Time End', y='Pressure')
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure')

# plot spans
colors = {1: '#D9E8FB', 2: '#F7CECC', 3: '#FFF2CD'}
for _, (x1, x2, c) in df1.iterrows():
    ax.axvspan(x1, x2, color=colors[c])
```

[image: line plot with vspans]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there any way to convert 'total seconds' to a time string in the format '%H:%M:%S'?